# segment fault when assigning a new allocated memory to a struct pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
struct Student {
public:
    string name;
    string family;
    string stdno;
    string ncode;
    float average;
    float age;
    struct Student *FL;
} *start, *cur, *p;

p = new struct Student;
    cur->FL = p;
    p->FL = NULL; // p->FL = nullptr in c++11
    cur = p;
```

I try assigning a new memory allocated to a structure pointer,It seems there is no issue but I get segment fault when `cur->FL = p;` ran, Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Where does `cur` point? You *do* initialize it before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cur has not been assigned anything to point to

cur = p;

Needs to be before p->FL

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is all at global scope, your `cur` pointer got initialized to null and dereferencing it to access the `FL` member will very likely break things. You need to make sure you initialize `cur`.